# Reuse template for HTML layout object

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I would like to add to my form layout an [HTML layout object](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects), reusing an existing template, but I have not been able to get it to work. This is what I am doing:

```
HTML(loader.get_template('my-template.html'))
```

But `get_template` is giving me a `Template`, not a string, and it breaks.

Can I do something else to get this working?

### EDIT

More rationale:

I am looking for the raw template string, since I want to **reuse** a template for a layout component, which will be rendered later in the context of the page being accessed. When it is rendered, I want it to behave as it would be rendered in a normal template processing step.

I would like to avoid pre-rendering because it seems unsafe to me, since I do not think that it is guaranteed that this gives me back exactly the same template string as I have in disk. And I would really like to avoid having another source of strange and hard to debug problems.

### EDIT2

This is my current, working hack (even on Heroku):

```
# TODO: this is a hack
template_str = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'my-template.html')).read()

    ...
    HTML(template_str),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the unmodified template string at `Template.source`:

```
template = loader.get_template('my-template.html')
HTML(template.source)
```

However I think it will be more efficient (and less magical) just to do:

```
HTML('{% include "my-template.html" %}')
```

Comment: That, my friend, did not occur to me, and it works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render_to_string()`:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

html = render_to_string('your-template.html', {})
HTML(html)
```

Comment: Without context? Will this process the template, and eventually return a modified version? I want the raw template file!

Comment: This will process the template yes. I assumed from your question that you were looking for a string, but if you need the un-rendered version then @solarissmoke's answer is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks brandon, yes, I am looking for the *raw template string*, since I want to **reuse** a template for a layout component, which will be rendered later in the context of the page being accessed. When it is rendered, I want it to behave as it would be rendered in a normal template processing step. That is why *pre-rendering* it seems unsafe to me, since I do not think that it is guaranteed that this gives me back exactly the same template string as I have in disk. And I would really like to avoid having *another* source of strange and hard to debug problems.